# Animate Scaling with RaphaelJS

Tags: javascript, animation, raphael

I'm trying to get the scaling animation to work with RaphaelJS, but I'm having no luck. This is what my code looks like:

> paper.animate({
>      scale : 2
>    });

But the animation doesn't work. Is this the correct way to animate a scale effect using RaphaelJS or is something that has to manually animated (using a JavaScript interval and so on...)?

-- EDIT --

My mistake, I was referring to an element.

elementFromPaper.animate({
  scale : 2
});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Paper` is a container of elements in Raphael, and it simply doesn't have the `animate` method.
Only the elements such as circles, rects, etc .. has the `animate` method.
If you want to change the size of the container, you can use [setSize](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.setSize).(But this will not scale any elements in the container).

EDIT: If you want to achieve an effect like zoom in or zoom out, you can use the [setViewBox](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.setViewBox) method.

EDIT2: `scale` is not in the list of element attributes, as listed in [here](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.attr)

To animate with scale, you can use the generic [transform](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.transform) parameter.

```
ele.animate({transform: 's2'}) // here `s2` means a 2x scale
```

I wrote a simple demo for you: http://jsfiddle.net/qiao/EhCyd/1/

Comment: My mistake, I was referring to an element not a paper canvas.

Answer (score 2):

The only native interaction with the canvas position is done through the method [setViewBox](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.setViewBox), however it doesn't animate a transition to the canvas position or zoom level. To achieve an animation, you can use a nifty javascript animation method [window.requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame) to smoothly transition to the viewBox state that you want.

First of all, initialize the method for all browsers:

```
    window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
    return  window.requestAnimationFrame   ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame      ||
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
        function( callback ){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
})();
```

Here is an example code for animating panning

```
var viewBoxX = 0;
var viewBoxY = 0;

//@param direction 'up', 'down', 'right' or 'left'
function pan(direction) {
    var start = Date.now();

    function step(timestamp) {
        var progress = timestamp - start;
        var x = viewBoxX,
            y = viewBoxY;

        if(direction == 'up') {
            y = viewBoxY - progress * 0.7;
        }
        else if (direction == 'down') {
            y = viewBoxY + progress * 0.7;
        }
        else if(direction == 'right') {
            x = viewBoxX + progress * 0.7;
        }
        else {
            x = viewBoxX - progress * 0.7;
        }

        //Now we set the view box at the modified x and y coordinates
        //Replace 100,100 with the size of your canvas
        paper.setViewBox(x, y, 100, 100);
        if (progress < 400) {
            window.requestAnimFrame(step);
        }
        else {
            viewBoxX = x;
            viewBoxY = y;
        }
    }
    window.requestAnimFrame(step);
}
```